# Slope intercept equation where b is the point on x-axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In our slope intercept formula: $y = mx + b$ where we know the value of $b$ is a point on $y$-axis. Can we write this as where $b$ is a point on $x$-axis?

E.g. our slope formula is:

$m = (y_2 - y_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$

We derive the slope intercept formula for x-axis by plugging $(b, 0)$:

$m = (y - 0)/(x - b)$

$m(x - b) = y$

So, we have a new formula as:
$x = y/m + b$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you realize the $b$ in $y=mx+b$ is different from the $b$ in $x=y/m+b$.

Comment: It is correct, but you should take care not to call the number $b$ the point and of course, it does not work if $m=0$.